# Need to Retrieve a string from a Google Maps Marker on tap

Tags: android, google-places-api

In my app I have a list of googlePlaceDetails objects (custom made class) which I have used to plot a bunch of markers on a google map fragment.

this is the googlePlaceDetails class:

```
public class googlePlaceDetails {

    String googlePlaceID;
    String placeName;    
    String placeAddress;    
    String rating;    
    String lat;
    String lng;    
}
```

This is how I have populated the markers on map.

```
List<googlePlaceDetails> output = //* populate the list here *//

for (int i=0; i< output.size() ; i++)
    {
        googlePlaceDetails place = output.get(i);

        double placeLat = Double.parseDouble(place.lat);
        double placeLng = Double.parseDouble(place.lng);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(placeLat, placeLng))
                .title(place.placeName)
                .snippet(place.placeAddress)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mapmarker_red)));

    }
```

Now I have a `"View Place Details"` button in my app. user taps on a marker to select a landmark, then taps on this `"View Place Details"` button to launch a new activity where he can see the detailed data.

This is how I have captured the marker click.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String placename = marker.getTitle();
            String placeAddress = marker.getSnippet();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I am able to retrieve the place name and address because I have supplied them in the marker's `Title` and `Snippet` properties while adding them.

My question is, how can I can feed the `googlePlaceID` String value in the marker while populating it so that I can retrieve the same when user taps on a marker? if it is not possible then what could be a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have an idea.

define

```
 private Map<LatLng, String> marker = new HashMap();
```

Now modify this function

```
for (int i=0; i< output.size() ; i++)
    {
        googlePlaceDetails place = output.get(i);

        double placeLat = Double.parseDouble(place.lat);
        double placeLng = Double.parseDouble(place.lng);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(placeLat, placeLng))
                .title(place.placeName)
                .snippet(place.placeAddress)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.mapmarker_red)));
        marker.put(yourlatlng,"string");

    }
```

Now in marker click you can get the value by parsing the HashMap

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String placename = marker.getTitle();
            String placeAddress = marker.getSnippet();

            /// iterate your map

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Modify according to your requirement.Maybe it can help

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<Marker, YourClass> hash = new HashMap<Marker, YourClass>();

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String placename = marker.getTitle();
            String placeAddress = marker.getSnippet();

            YourClass object = hash.get(marker);
            object.****

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am using a custom icon anyway so there is no problem using a custom view for my marker. can I extend the marker or markeroptions to add additional properties?